# Custom Error Messages in Node Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, error-handling, iisnode

Stumbled across an interesting issue with an Azure Web App running Node with IIS and wanted to share because I couldn't find information on it.

**The problem:**

My custom error messages weren't making it down to the client on my production app but were coming through just fine locally.

Quick example:

```
app.post('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    // Parse out the user data
    // ...
    // Oh no! An error!
    if (invalidData) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Invalid username, must be at least 4 characters.'});
    }
    // ...
});
```

This was coming through my Web App as the standard "400: Bad request..." message rather than my custom error message. On the client I was trying to do `JSON.parse(err.responseText).error` which wasn't working as `err.responseText` was the `"Bad request..."` string rather than my JSON object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The solution!**

In your `web.config` file add this line between `<system.webServer> ... </system.webServer>`:

`<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`

Hopefully nobody else hits this issue like I did. I'm sure it was a mix of incorrect googling and inexperience with IIS but I never actually found the answer online, I stumbled across a few links that led me to the [IIS error handling page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).

Hope this helps someone else! There's a ton of good info in that doc if you're running an IIS web app, I highly recommend reading through it.